# Trimming white spaces

Tags: java

Is there any inbuilt method for trimming only trailing white spaces from a string?
that is similar to rtrim available in other languages

Example:
String str1 = "stackoverflow        ";
String str2 = "       stackoverflow        ";

should become,

str1 = "stackoverflow"; 
str2 = "       stackoverflow";

Comment: Did you even searched for it on google?

Comment: You mean trailing white-space?

Comment: @FirmView - Thanks for abusing the site...

Answer (score 3):

String has method called [trim();](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

`str1.trim();` will do the job for you.

Update:

If you don't want to trim() leading spaces, you may need to write your own implementation as DNA suggested.

Comment: @FirmView.. Your understanding of trailing and leading is reverse.

Comment: @FirmView: Erm, what? Look at your example.

Comment: @FirmView: Please spend sometime to understand what you want achieve.

Answer (score 3):

How about checking the [source code](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/lang/String.java.html) for `String.trim()` and modifying it?

Disabling the whitespace removal at the start or the end is a matter of commenting out one line...

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a regex or iterate over the string to remove whitespace characters.

Either way, you should read the documentation here:  [Java String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

Plenty of ways to do this, regex being one of them:

To remove trailing whitespaces:

```
s/\s+$//
```

Somewhat related, but probably not what you're looking for, to remove leading whitespaces:

```
s/^\s+//
```

PS: I believe you mean to say trailing whitespaces, as leading whitespaces imply that the whitespaces come first.